# GWT - popup menu with submenus - advise some UI lib

Tags: gwt

I am looking for some kind of GWT library which has popup menu with submenu(s) support; I mean something like [this](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/doc-files/MenuBar.png) **but with no upper menu bar** because I need to have it visible on some Button click for example;

something like this instead of the MenuBar:

[image]

So I need your practical advice where can I find a gwt library which supports that kind of component(s) ? I know it is popup menu(s) combination but I am interested to find an optimal framework solution or something which is not too heavy...

P.S> GWT 2.3

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1 -

A BareBones implementation using only native GWT would go like this :

```
public void onModuleLoad()
{
    MenuBar options = new MenuBar( true );
    MenuBar gwtPopup = new MenuBar( true );
    options.addItem( "GWT", gwtPopup );
    MenuItem entryPoint = new MenuItem( new SafeHtmlBuilder().appendEscaped( "EntryPoint" ).toSafeHtml() );
    entryPoint.setScheduledCommand( new ScheduledCommand()
    {
        public void execute()
        {
            Window.alert( "hello" );
        }
    } );
    final DialogBox menuWrapper = new DialogBox( true );
    menuWrapper.add( options );
    gwtPopup.addItem( entryPoint );
    Button showMenu = new Button( "Click me", new ClickHandler()
    {
        public void onClick( ClickEvent event )
        {
            menuWrapper.showRelativeTo( menuWrapper );
        }
    } );

    RootPanel.get().add( showMenu );
}
```

### Solution 2 -

We typically found it hard to style popup, menu item and handle it other quirky behaviors. So instead we just wrapped sequence of buttons in vertical panel, styled it as needed and display it in a DialogBox.

### Solution 3 - Third party libs

1. GwtQuery - You can wrap your own based on a jquery one.
2. GXT
3. Vaadin
4. GWTBootstrap
5. JSNI over jquery, bootstrap or any other favorite js lib

Comment: So you suggest to place the MenuBar to DialogBox? I actually wanted to make MenuBar invisible or something because I want to have its submenus being shown only :S How you think is there a way to add menuitem to lets say Button widget?

Comment: You would need to show the menu on button click and hide it on any outside click or by timer. DialogBox is the widget from GWT that most suits that feature. You can either use MenuBar or you own Composite Widget wrapping VerticalPanel having sequence of buttons.

Comment: Emm... I just wanted to ask... what module should I inherit for this ScheduledCommand object? I have gwt 2.3

Comment: Check the MenuItem class whether you need the deprecated setCommand api instead. ScheduledCommand might be from 2.5 onwards

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no UI libraries especially for popups and submenus. As for your requirement is considered, You can implement your own widget for that. Create a flowpanel or Horizontal panel. Insert 2 images in that, one for menu image and another for arrow image. Add a click handler to your arrow image and show the required popup.

Comment: "As far as I know there are no UI libraries especially for popups and submenus..." I suspect that too :) I just want to find a lib as lightweight as possible with this kind of popup menus support; For example I watched smartGWT but it is too heavy as for my case... so maybe there is something more light?

Comment: smartGwt and gxt are not light. I suspect there are no light weight libraries

Comment: Really :S I thought maybe someone could hear some useful lib from the incubator or something...